# Get href attribute from dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

This is the code I'm using to try and get all the hrefs ONLY from the nav:

```
componentDidMount(){
    $("nav ul li a").each(function(k, j){
      console.log(j);
    });
  }
```

From this I am successfully getting all of the dom elements printed out on the console as such:

```
<a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
<a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
...etc...
```

Now to try and actually pull out the href string, I've attempted many things such as trying to `console.log(j.attr('href'))` (in the loop shown above), but have nothing working yet. (TypeError: j.attr is not a function)

What should I use for this? and also my application is built in ReactJS so I was wondering if there was maybe a more appropriate way to achieve this, with something such as `refs`

Many thanks

Comment: `j` is the element ... `.attr` is a jQuery method ... so `$(j).attr` will get you what is needed .... or just `j.href` if you want to do things efficiently

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(j.href)` I don't use jQuery much so just a guess but maybe `$(j).attr('href');`

Comment: Cool. Your suggestions are getting me `http://localhost:3000/#home` from each of them. I'll just slice from # onwards to get the actual href. thanks guys

Comment: actually checking again JaromandaX's second solution using `$(j).attr('href')` extracts the href string along without the whole url. Wonder what the difference is between the two. Oh well it works,  Thx again

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get rid of slicing the string which u get using j.href, you can even use getAttribute on j.

```js
$("a").each(function(k, j) {
  console.log(j.getAttribute("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
<a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$("a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
<a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

one line change in your code

```js
     $("nav ul li a").each(function(k, j){
          console.log($(this).attr('href'));
        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```